# Custom radio button style not reset after reset button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

The reset button need to click twice to work (remove the selected class of label).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".model-list li input").click(function(e) {
    $(".model-list li label").removeClass("selected");
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
    }
  });
  initBtns();
  $(".reset-btn").click(function() {
    initBtns();
  });

  function initBtns() {
    $(".model-list li").each(function(e) {
      if ($(this).find('input').is(":checked")) {
        $(this).find('label').addClass("selected");
      } else {
        $(this).find('label').removeClass("selected");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

This is the jsfiddle result: 
`https://jsfiddle.net/qh8f3rw6/`

Thanks.

Comment: look like the default behavior of `input[type=reset]` change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that the `reset` of the form is actually happen only **after** your `initBtns` function actually runs.
What you actually need to do is call the `reset()` function before the `initBtns()`:

```
$(".reset-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').get(0).reset();
    initBtns();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go with a css only solution:

wrap the labels in an element:

```
<li>
  <label class="cursor">
    <input type="radio" name="model" value="64" /> <span>64 GB</span>    
  </label>
</li>
```

so that you can style it with css only:

```
.model-list li label input:checked + span {
  border: 1px solid #3c8dbc;
  background: #eaeaea;
}
```

**demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/qh8f3rw6/2/